# Deployed Laravel: 404 error. not linking to pages

Tags: deployment, laravel, lighttpd

I'm pretty new with Laravel. Recently I finished my first App and deployed it on my raspberry pi server (lighttpd). After configuring the database access I went to http://web.web.com/app/public, desplaying the main page with no problems shown.

But then, when I click on a link, any link, its brings up a 404 error (page not found). The browser apparently tried to access the correct url:

http://we.web.com/app/public/route_name

What did i miss to configure????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to set the **document root** to `dir-to-your-app/public`.

so instead of calling http://we.web.com/app/public you'd want to call http://we.web.com/app.

if you don't have other hostings you could set the global document root in your lighttpd conf to your laravel projects's public. if you have other stuff to host, you may want to add a virtual host.